# SELECT2 AJAX - Action after success call

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to do some action after user selected a value, please advice the way to do so. 
For example, once user picked "Apple", I want to alert('You picked Apple for $15') and etc.

**JQuery**

```
$("#dd1").select2({
  placeholder: "Search for fruit",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {
    url: "something.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        str: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }            
});
```

**something.php**

```
$data = [
  ['id'=>'1','text'=>'Apple','price'=>'15'],
  ['id'=>'2','text'=>'Banana','price'=>'16'],
  ['id'=>'3','text'=>'Orange','price'=>'17']
]
return json_encode($data)
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select2:select` event:

```
$('#dd1').on('select2:select', function (e) {
   alert(`You picked ${e.params.data.text} for $${e.params.data.price}`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very close to what I want, I am using e.params.data["price"] instead